# how to filter product from front end in magento site

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

How customer filter products via price, brand, and another feature of products in Magento site like paytm, I am using Magento 1.9 version.

I want to show a feature of the product in the left side bar, and then a customer can filter product via these functions.

Answer (score 1):

Please find the following step

Goto Admin panel

Catalog->Manage Categories
Click on your category then goto Display Setting Tab

Set Is Anchor -> yes
now you'll set filter options in left side bar.

If you not get the filter,

in admin panel category edit check Custom design Tab

set page layout as 2columns-left.phmtl or 3columns.phtml

or check your catalog.xml file in that make sure the category view page template is 2columns-left.phmtl or 3columns.phtml

Comment: i have set this but price and category shows only, i want to show more like brand name and another feature of prodcuts